# Time Zone Query for Summer Offsets

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a little windows application that converts UK, US and NZ time zones when the datetime picker is changed but I feel that my code isn't taking into consideration the various summer and winter offsets. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        TimeZoneInfo nzZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("New Zealand Standard Time");
        TimeZoneInfo ukZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
        TimeZoneInfo usZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");

        DateTime nzZone1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimePicker1.Value, TimeZoneInfo.Local, nzZone);
        DateTime ukZone1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimePicker1.Value, TimeZoneInfo.Local, ukZone);
        DateTime usZone1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimePicker1.Value, TimeZoneInfo.Local, usZone);

        label4.Text = nzZone1.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        label5.Text = ukZone1.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        label6.Text = usZone1.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
```

Comment: Can you give an example? Expected input/output?

Comment: Actually, I can't, I had a look on Google to see when NZ and UK change the times and the above code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ok. Your doubt has to do with the fact that both UK and New Zeland timezones implement Daylight changes. You can see the effect you expect if you create another TimeZoneInfo which not implements Daylight changes e.g. UTC and test with two quite different dates as January 1st and July 1st.

```
     TimeZoneInfo utcZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");
     DateTime utcZone1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimePicker1.Value, TimeZoneInfo.Local, utcZone);
     labelutc.Text = utcZone1.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
```